# Jruby 1.6.3 and Rails 3.1 coffeescript bug

Tags: jruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I cannot get coffeescript working from rails 3.1 in jurby 1.6.3.

HTTP requests for `/assets/application.js` are failing with `TypeError: can't convert Hash into String. It works fine under MRI 1.9.2.`

After a bout of ruby-debug-ide debugging issues (I’m looking at you Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `is_binary_data?'); I believe I have it narrowed down to the following:

Line 141 of external_runtime.rb for ExecJS (a coffee-script dependency) appears to be where this TypeError is cropping up:

```
IO.popen(command, options) { |f| output = f.read }
```

Poking around `jira.codehaus.org` I stumbled onto JRUBY-5532 which is fixed, but Charles Nutter noted that other IO calls ignore encoding options, which makes me wonder if this is an IO issue with JRuby’s 1.9 support.

Regardless, I’m looking for a workaround, fix, or any other information available to try and get this to a working state. After all, no pain – no gain.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use Coffeescript?